# Why can elements of the SL(N) group be represented through the e-function near the unity?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I've read many times that an element $g \in SL(N)$  can be represented in an area around $\mathbb{1} $ as $g=e^{X}$. Of course there is always the possibility that $X=ln(g)$ but that would work for any group.

I would be interested in a simple explanation why this statement is true since it doesn't seem to be trivial (at least not for me)?

Comment: Is $N$ a vector space? Over what field and in what dimension? Have you ever encountered objects (groups, algebras) with the name "Lie" in them?

Comment: N denotes the dimension and yes, I'm talking about Lie groups. SL(N) stands for the special linear group of the dimension N.